# rig character collection append problem

Tags: rigging, append

I downloaded a free rigged character and appended it to my blender file.
[image]

it looks like this. on the right panel, some of the objects are active. however, the collection called 'BoneShapes' is not active. **when I try to append this file to another file, I want to copy the collection just like the original one.** do you guys know how to do this?

and I appended the character like this,

[image]

it shows everything, including objects which were hidden on the original file.
but its bones work well in the first loading place where all the objects are gathered.
I can rotate or move all the legs and arms, Just like the creator made it.
as below
[image]

but I change the location of the character to the background scene like this, to remove all the messy things that are still there on the first loading spot.
[image]

suddenly, I can't move or rotate the right arm like below.
even the movement I applied at first loading spot was disappeared.
(on the third picture I upload, the character are stretching his both arms, but whenever I move the character his right arm has no movement at all)

[image]

by the way the area of the object I chose to move is like this.

[image]

**I wanna know how to move the right arm when I move the character location.**
it would be sooo grateful to somebody who knows this to tell me:)

the character I use is from  this link (on the description)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2yn5I9B0Im4

rigs pictures(edit version)
[image: at first loading spot, I can move right arm here]

[image: I slightly moved the character to the upper side, and can't move the right arm]

Comment: your wrote " the collection called 'BoneShapes' is not active" -- try clicking on the empty square next to the BoneShapes collection to enable it.  You should then be able to expaned it and select.  Similar if you need to select the Head object: click on the grayed out screen (on its right) to be able to enable it in viewport, to select it if you need.

Comment: you wrote "suddenly, I can't move or rotate the right arm" -- did you move the rig or the mesh... looks like you didn't move the rig as that you be what you need to relocate and the mesh should follow.   As with posing, you want to operate on the rig.

Comment: thanks for your comment! but what I'm curious about is that the original file has the collection called 'BoneShapes' and it's kinda linked to the upper collection, but the creator hides it cuz it looks messy I guess. so when I append the character file to another file all the hierarchy that the creator made on the collection box became disappeared. so I wanna keep the same hierarchy that the original file has on the collection box when I append that file to another file...! do you know how to do this?

Comment: and how can I know that rigs are on the right spot...? cuz I turned to the edit mode and compared the character in the different locations, but it looks the same to me haha... (I added the edit version of captures) It's my first time playing with rigs. by the way, thanks a lot for your quick response!!

Comment: my first comment (above) was how to enable and view your BoneShapes collection, and you could Append that Collection as you import if for some reason these become useful or your pose/animations somehow depend on them (IK?).   I also get quite a lot of baggage and disabled Collections when I use the DAZ import tools and am still learning myself.   
   
-----
  I discovered I learn blender quicker by sometimes spending time answering questions so it's actually a good time investment in education -- like being part of a lab team in school.

Comment: totally agree!! thank you for letting me know about the 'appending the collection'. my collection section seems organized better than before! thanks a lot! btw the problem of that I can move the right arm is solved! I've learned that I should change the location of the rigged character in pose mode (not obect mode), by clicking the base of the character :) have a great day!

Comment: someone once said: "this stuff should be easier!"

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is locate where all these extra boneshapes are and <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>Left Click</kbd>  the eye button to hide.
Like this:

Before:
[image: 1:]

After <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>Left Click</kbd> eye icon:
[image: Shift+Click eye icon and they dissapears]